# Trying to get all records that have a timestamp in between two given dates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, time

I have this huge database of records that have been created over the past 5 or so years. I'm thinking it would be cool (and edifying) to try to create some time categories/segments for these records, the unit could be week or month or something like that, something to use for a graph.

Anyway, I need to develop a query that, given a datetime attr for each record in the table, would return all the records with a datetime falling in between X and Y (June 1, 2011 & June 7, 2011, for example).

I'm not good at using the time helpers yet and could not find any sufficiently similar questions on SO or elsewhere.

Solutions that use subjective increments like "week" or "month" *that rails can understand* would be strongly appreciated. I know how tricky the calendar can get in programming. Or I could just use some lowest common denominator (day) and do an extremely fine graph.

Comment: I'm currently working on the LCD method, which will basically involve me querying each day individually and essentially obtaining a "velocity" of company_accts_created/day. If rails and/or ruby has some elegant, edifying ruby-like way to do this, please chime in. I'm also open to (interested in) SQL based solutions

Comment: What does increments like week or month have to do with finding records between a given date X & Y?

Comment: In a graph, which is what I'm trying to output here, the x axis would be measured in terms of time....visually, to the user, those chunks of time might be measured out in weeks, months, or days. Not seconds, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Client.where(:created_at => X..Y)
```

Source: [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)